# ReactBootstrap global is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

so I'm currently working on a project written in Flask which I added Bootstrap to. I have recently started adding some react components and I would like to have them look like the other bootstrapped components. Here is some of my code:

This is where I've included my bootstrap.js files and react.js file

```
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/react-bootstrap-bower/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

This html normally is rendered by bootstrap as wonderful little pager icons, but not in react:

```
return (
        <div>
            <nav> 
                <ul className="pagination pagination-lg">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

I understand I didn't put the full return, the return isn't the issue at hand, however, its the styling. I tried adding in a Pager element with the following

```
var Pager = ReactBootstrap.Pager;
...
//inside some html return
<Pager></Pager>
```

but I get the response first that ReactBootstrap is not defined. Yet I read that the ReactBootstrap global is created automatically when you include the js file. The other response is that Pager doesn't exist (obviously since ReactBootstrap was unable to return it).

So my question is, can I simply return html without the data-reactid info or somehow have it rendered by bootstrap without needing reactBootstrap? or do is there something I'm missing from my files to use reactBootstrap. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dogudubuvu/3/edit?html,js,output), but ReactBootstrap.Pager is a component, and it renders with the correct styles.

You're not loading things correctly.